# list associated data by a consecutive number with php, js, mysql, ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to send data that are related by a formula number but in the code that I have managed to do, it only sends me one piece of information and I would like it to show me all those that have the same formula number. I would really appreciate your help this is my code:

here the data that will be sent is listed

```
case "buscar_DproductoB";
  $datos=$Dproducto->get_DproductoP($_POST["id_detalle_Dproducto"], $_POST["estado"]);
   if(is_array($datos)==true and count($datos)>0){
        foreach($datos as $row)
        {
           $output["id_detalle_Dproducto"] = $row["id_detalle_Dproducto"];
          $output["id_Mprima"] = $row["id_Mprima"];
          $output["materiales"] = $row["materiales"];
          $output["unidadm"] = $row["unidadm"];
          $output["cantidad"] = $row["cantidad"];
          $output["moneda"] = $row["moneda"];
          $output["precio"] = $row["precio"];
          $output["estado"] = $row["estado"];
        }
        } else {            
                 $output["error"]="";
          }
    echo json_encode($output);
```

here if the data is active send it to sight

```
public function get_DproductoP($id_detalle_Dproducto,$estado){
          $conectar= parent::conexion();
          $estado=1;
          $sql="select * from detalle_Dproducto where id_detalle_Dproducto=? and estado=?";
          $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
          $sql->bindValue(1, $id_detalle_Dproducto);
          $sql->bindValue(2, $estado);
          $sql->execute();
          return $resultado= $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
    }
```

and this is the part that by means of a button sends the data to view

```
var detalles = [];
   function agregarDetalleB(id_detalle_Dproducto,materiales,estado){

    //alert(estado);
            $.ajax({
          url:"../ajax/Dproducto.php?op=buscar_DproductoB",
           method:"POST",
          data:{id_detalle_Dproducto:id_detalle_Dproducto,materiales:materiales,estado:estado},
          cache: false,
          dataType:"json",
          success:function(data){
                     if(data.id_detalle_Dproducto){
            if (typeof data == "string"){
                  data = $.parseJSON(data);
            }
            console.log(data);              
            var obj = {
              Nbatida : 1,
              codDD  : id_detalle_Dproducto, 
              codDpro   : data.id_Mprima,
              materiales : data.materiales,
              unidadm  : data.unidadm,
              precio   : data.precio,
              cantidad : data.cantidad,
              moneda   : data.moneda,
              importe  : 0,
              estado   : data.estado
              };                   
            detalles.push(obj);
            listarDetallesB();
            $('#modalDproducto').modal("hide");
                       }
                        else {           
                            bootbox.alert(data.error);
                        }  
          }
        });   
      }
```

```
function listarDetallesB(){

      
    $('#listMpriBatida').html('');

  

    var filas = "";
    
    var subtotal = 0;

    var total = 0;

    var subtotalFinal = 0;

    var totalFinal = 0;


    for(var i=0; i<detalles.length; i++){
    if( detalles[i].estado == 1 ){

      var importe = detalles[i].importe = detalles[i].Nbatida * detalles[i].cantidad * detalles[i].precio;
     
        
        importe = detalles[i].importe;
        
      var filas = filas + "<tr><td>"+(i+1)+
      "</td> <td><input type='number'  class='Nbatida input-group-sm' name='Nbatida[]' id='Nbatida[]' onClick='setNbatida(event, this, "+
      (i)+");' onKeyUp='setNbatida(event, this, "+(i)+");' value='"+detalles[i].Nbatida+
      "'></td><td name='materiales[]'>"+detalles[i].materiales+"</td><td name='unidadm[]'>"+
      detalles[i].unidadm+"</td> <td name='precio[]' id='precio[]'>"+
      detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].precio+"</td> <td> <span name='cantidad[]' id='cantidad"+i+
      "'> "+detalles[i].cantidad+"</span> </td> <td> <span name='importe[]' id='importe"+i+
      "'>"+detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].importe+
       "</span> </td><td>  <button href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' role='button' onClick='eliminarBa(event, "+
       (i)+");' aria-pressed='true'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> </button></td> </tr>";
      subtotal = subtotal + importe;
```

Comment: Just use `echo json_encode($datos);` That's the whole array. You're just returning the last row.

Comment: You don't need to call `$.parseJSON()`, jQuery does that automatically when you use `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: thanks friend now if you show them in cosola only that you can not add them to edit

Comment: In JavaScript it will be an array of objects, not a single object.

Comment: So you can't access `data.id_Mprima`, you need to loop over the array and get `data[i].id_Mprima`.

Comment: that way for all fields?

Comment: Excuse me, I'm new programming

Comment: Yes, all the fields are like that. That's how you get the data for all the rows returned by the query, instead of just one row.

Comment: Excuse me, how can I do that?

Comment: `data[i].materiales` and the same for all the other fields.

Comment: It is added to all those who carry data. but it doesn't add them yet. Should I add it to two that don't have the data?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Add what to what?

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { console.log(data[i]); }` will show all of them.

Comment: add the following part of code where you list the data